# Importing only one task from gradle file

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

Am I right that there is no way to import only one `task` from script file into a project? I have utility `task` which should be in a list of tasks.

```
task utiliyTask{
  description 'Utility task which you could to run when you need it'
  funA()
  funB()  
}

def funA(){
  //...
}

def funB(){
  //...
}
```

Putting `apply from` into a project's `build.gradle` file executes this task automatically which is wrong. The only solution which I found is [creating plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html), but it seems like overkill to create a plugin for 100 lines of utility script

Comment: Can you give a runnable example that shows the problem?  Not sure what you mean as it stands :-(

Comment: @tim_yates there is no runnable problem. The question is about way of creating utility(reusable) scripts. I have `task` which should be in a list of tasks. I just want to be sure that there're only two methods of doing this: creating plugin and adding script file with task via `apply from`

Comment: Ahhh...  change `task utiliyTask{` to `task utiliyTask << {` then use `apply from:`

Comment: Ahhh! It works as I need. Thanks! You could add answer and I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: @tim_yates the other problem with `<<` is that description disappears, `utiliyTask` is in list but without description. Without `<<` description exists.

Comment: how about `task utiliyTask { description 'blah' } << {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply add task execution code into `doLast`

```
task utiliyTask{
  description 'Utility task which you could to run when you need it'
  doLast {
    funA()
    funB()
  }  
}
```